I need to downgrade from 5.9.9 to latest 5.8.x - where is the db instructions executed when upgrading?
When I upgraded 5.8 to 5.9 my db was updated by WP.
Where are located db upgrade functions?
I want to consult them because I need a downgrade from 5.9 to 5.8
We haven't upgraded any plugin yey, but some plugins are having bad behaviours
First time for me trying to downgrade a WP

if the goal is to downgrade then you don't need to modify the database yourself, WordPress overwrites the table schemas. As a sidenote upgrading WP should not cause major issues in plugins if they are built correctly using the proper APIs, likewise staging environments and testing can mitigate these ( WP 5.9 is also very old, we're coming up to WP 6.7 )

This is the file where upgrades take place
wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php


"First time for me trying to downgrade a WP"
That would be one time too much...
I am actually not familiar with any software that you can downgrade (for many tools, the version is just misleadingly give the impression there is some incremental continuation while the truth is that it is a totally different product, a good example is all the versions of windows, they called windows but they don't even look the same)
The only way to downgrade is to restore from backup, but then you will lose whatever DB changes that were made during the time. If there were only few changes, it is way safer to restore from backup and reapply the changes.
.... but at some point you will need to upgrade (and you are already several versions behind) so it might be more productive to figure out the problems and fix them now instead of kicking the can down the road ;)

I agree but I'm in a situation where I can't tell NO the client and to my boss. Anyway, as per my own answer, I found where upgrade is handled, so I discovered that I can downgrade easily because db-side there aren't variations

@realtebo this is a little simplistic, if all the stars are alligned you might be good but the stars must include themes and plugins as well for which it is harder to know if an upgrade changes the DB. So you might be good but generaly a bad idea, and if your boss and client do not get it, maybe you should try to explain to them the risk
